# Base64 Encoded Image String Not Working In CSS Background-Image Property (C#, ASP.NET, Razor)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I am currently working on a C# ASP.NET web app written in the MVC framework. Currently, I have hit a bottleneck in building my view. You can see the code for the view in the following:

```
@model Vote.Models.DashboardViewModelHolder
@{    
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DashboardLayout.cshtml";
}

@*<div class="st_overlay"></div>*@ 

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">

     <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.national_Elected_Officials.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i.Equals(0))
            {
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to=@i class="active"></li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to=@i></li>
            }
        }        
    </ol>

    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <!-- Utilize a foreach loop here because you dont need to access the iterator for incremental
        calculation. Build the div class = "item", "class ="fill" and the class="carousel-caption"
        inside the foreach loop. -->
        @foreach (var electedOfficial in Model.national_Elected_Officials)
        {
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(electedOfficial.Picture);
            string imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);

            if (electedOfficial.ElectedOfficialID.Equals(1) && electedOfficial.Branch.Equals("Executive "))
            {
                <div class="item active">

                    <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->           
                    <img class="fill" src="@imgSrc" />
                    @*<div class="fill" style="background-image: url(imgSrc);"></div>*@   


                    <div class="carousel-caption">           
                        <h1>@electedOfficial.Position.ToString() @electedOfficial.FirstName.ToString() @electedOfficial.LastName.ToString()</h1>
                        <p><h3>Party:</h3> 
                        <br />
                        @electedOfficial.Party.ToString()
                        </p>
                        <p><h3>Terms Served In Office In Current Position:</h3> 
                        <br />
                        @electedOfficial.Terms
                        </p>
                        <p><h3>Years Served In Office In Current Position:</h3>
                        <br />
                         @electedOfficial.YearsOfService
                        </p>
                        <p><h3>General Description Of @electedOfficial.FirstName @electedOfficial.LastName:</h3>
                        <br />
                        @electedOfficial.Bio
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            else if (!electedOfficial.ElectedOfficialID.Equals(1) && electedOfficial.Branch.Equals("Executive "))
            {
                <div class="item">
                    <img class="fill" src="@imgSrc" />
                    @*<div class="fill" style="background-image: url(imgSrc);"></div>*@
                    @*<div style="background:url(data:image/jpeg;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(electedOfficial.Picture))"></div>*@

                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>@electedOfficial.FirstName @electedOfficial.LastName</h2>
                        <p>@electedOfficial.Party</p>
                        <p>@electedOfficial.Position</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }

        }
    </div>

    <!-- Carousel nav -->

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

</div>
```

The encoded string for the image data does get into the view correctly because the following line works:

```
<img class="fill" src="@imgSrc" />
```

However, I need this picture to act as a background image that fits to scale of the user's monitor (no scrollbars). To do this, I tried the following:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image: url(imgSrc);"></div>
```

Unfortunately, the above line of code gets skipped over when I debug line by line in Visual Studio. Due to this, the image does not appear whatsoever.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get an expression to be evaluated by the razor engine, you must prefix it with `@`.

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image: url(@imgSrc);"></div>
```

Edit for update: You haven't included enough information to know what the new problem is, but here is an example of an inline base64 background image.  So whatever your code does different than this code, change it.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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)"></div>
```

Comment: I did try to use the @ symbol but the screen is still blank. Inspecting the html on the view from the browser, I see this <div class="fill" style="background-image: url(data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA...)"></div>. The string is there but the image wont show.

Comment: @NickOrmsby: I added some info to my answer.  Short version is you haven't provided enough info to identify the problem.

Comment: I have the following inside my view: 

var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(electedOfficial.Picture);
string imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", base64); 
<div class="fill" style="background-image: url(@imgSrc)"></div>

And the following in my CSS:

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

And when I run my code, I get the full encoded image data string in my div but the image does not appear.

Comment: Without changing anything, the following works: 

<img class="fill" src="@imgSrc" />

Let me know if I can provide additional info!

Comment: @NickOrmsby:  It looks like it should work.  Could you copy the complete html of one of your failing `div`s to jsfiddle or something?

Comment: Heres the one where it works: https://jsfiddle.net/354zfdud/1/

Heres the one that doesnt work: https://jsfiddle.net/354zfdud/2/

Can you see something obvious that Im missing?

Comment: In your example, the background image is applying properly.  The problem is that the height of your div is `100%` of nothing, so you can't see the image.  If you use a pixel based height instead, you'll see it.  As a side note, trying to manipulate the example seemed to de-stabilize my browser.  The css rule is over 700kB.  Why not use regular images?

Comment: Ok that makes sense! Thank you so much for clearing that up! I wanted to use the background-image property because I didnt want scrollbars on my view. While the <img> tag works and displays correctly, there is a horizontal scrollbar. Do you know a way that the <img> tag can be manipulated to prevent scrollbars? '

Comment: There are lots of ways of accomplishing that.  The best way is probably to constrain the width of the img to the container.

Comment: Ok, after playing around with the HTML and CSS I got it to work. The reason for the scrollbar was because of a child div that wasnt well formatted. Regardless, thanks a bunch for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think, your `imgSrc` does not contains complete image URL .. Try some thing like

```
style="background-image:url('/oneFolder/secondFolder/img.jpg')
```

Comment: The image I am trying to utilize is stored in my SQL db as a byte[]. I am trying to utilize the image byte[] as a base64 encoded string to work with my div that has an inline CSS background-image property. For some reason, the Visual Studio debugger skips over the line assigning the encoded data string to the background image property.